# How to make an Axis network camera appear as a local webcam camera?

Tags: webcam, video-streaming, camera

I am trying to interface with an Axis 210 network camera. I can access it through web browser or some video stream URL. But I really want it to appear as a local webcam since many tools support that better.

I imagine there might be a tool that I can configure to interface the Axis camera, and then it will virtualize the Axis camera as a local webcam. Any one knows such tool, or similar ways to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to use a Axis Network camera and integrate it into for example skype or another application that typical looks for a web cam is to use "Axis Streaming Assistant"

[Axis Streaming Assistant](http://www.axis.com/techsup/software/asa/software.php)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried this but it looks like an official solution. I will adopt your answer for now and do test later.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.webcamxp.com/download.aspx says it will do what you want. "Our Directshow Filter allows to connect network cameras providing JPEG images or MJPEG streams in application accepting webcam sources like as Skype or Windows Media Encoder."

Otherwise, I would look at ManyCam Pro on Windows, and CamTwist Studio on OS X and see if they would help.

Comment: Just tried webcamxp. It works as advertised except there's some noticeable video delay which may or may not because of my specific setup. The vendor also provides a Direct Show filter for easier integration with 3rd party apps: http://dl.filekicker.com/send/file/226163-6E45/IPCameraDS.exe. Thanks for the helpful answer.

Comment: BTW, I didn't find CamTwist Studio can solve the problem. And ManyCam looks not either. If you think otherwise, please kindly let me know.

Comment: CamTwist can, but not nicely - you could open the Axis camera in a web browser, then clip that as an area of the screen to capture as sn input in CamTwist and refeed it as a fake webcam. I don't know ManyCam, but it does claim it can restream video sources so there might be a way of converting the camera output into a manycam compatible input.